# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor how go get number inside span tag

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

How can I get the integer number highlighted at this specific location:

[image: number inside span tag]

I got the follwing XPath from Google Chrome:

```
//*[@id="page"]/main/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/span
```

So I definded the following XPath statement with srapy to retreive the number:

```
id = response.xpath('//*[@id="page"]/main/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/span').extract()
```

However the variable id remains empty, my spider doesn't seem to crawl any information. How should I rewrite the statement to have access to this specific element?

Comment: Try with this xpath:  //*[@class='nr']/span

Comment: Works fantastic, thank you...

Comment: You're welcome :), I added the comment as answer, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, to avoid later debugging to have a stable run you need to avoid using absolute xpath's or any xpath that is not flexible on minor changes of the page structure.

From the information available in the picture, your xpath should be:

```
//*[@class='nr']/span
```

For basic overview of the xpath rule you can take a look on [w3schools xpath selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)